# Android Stop thread within Activity when Activity in Destroyed

Tags: android, multithreading, tcp

I have an Activity which creates a Thread in onStart() method.
The Thread is used for reading network data over TCP and has a blocking network read method within a while loop which checks a boolean variable on each increment.

My problem is that when the Activity is Destroyed using the back key, I set the value of the boolean loop control variable to false, but the thread wont finish as it is stuck on the blocking network method.

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Runnable
{
    Thread thread;
    boolean loopControl;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        loopControl=true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(loopControl)
        {
            directories = (Vector<String>) TCPFunctions.inputStream.readObject();
        }
    }

    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        loopcontrol = false;
    }
}
```

how do I finish such thread as I want it to because it creates a problem when this Activity is launched again.

Actually every time the activity starts it has some data to read from the Server

Answer (score 0):

in your onDestroy() method try

```
thread.interrupt();  
thread=null;
```

Comment: didn't help, old thread still runs and a new thread is created again when the Activity is launched again after destroying. When the activity is started again it gets some initialization data from server which actually is read by the old thread, and the new thread is left empty (check the last line of my post, just updated)

Comment: @Anjanu Try implementing the Runnable in a class other than your MainActivity.

Comment: @Anjanu You should be also checking for interrupt flag in the main thread loop... something like  `while (!thread.interrupted) { do backgroundwork}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still kind of new at Android but I'll give it a shot:

Are you sure that your onDestroy() method is called? Perhaps you are just exiting your app using the Home or Back button, and in those cases the onDestroy() method would not necessarily be called at all as showed in the diagram on this page:
[Activity Lifecycle - Pausing](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

Maybe you want the thread to stop its work when the app becomes 'hidden' and put this in onStop() instead:

```
loopcontrol = false;
thread.interrupt();  
thread=null;
```

If that is the case, also the onCreate() will not necessarily be called when you return/restart the app, so maybe the thread starting should be in the onResume()?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

Starting a background thread from one of the Activity callbacks methods is likely not a good idea in this case. Activity may be destroyed and recreated from scratch (for example, this is default behavior on rotating the phone) and in that case you will lose your thread...

The better way  could be to create [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)... But there are a lot of questions/answers here on SO about tcp communications from activity/Services/other things.

Comment: ok will try service...actually I was in a similar situation long back when working with UDP sockets...there I had set a socket timeout of 2 sec...so the blocking statement threw an Exception after every 2 seconds and it the Catch block I called the whole function again recursively were it got a chance to check the value of loop control variable...but is it fair to use Exception handling this way...just asking